# anchor popupmenu to actionbar's overflow view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, popupmenu

I have a menuItem in the actionbar that displays a popupMenu when clicked.

For smaller screen sizes, the menuItem is overflowed.
I like to anchor the popupMenu to the overflow icon when that happens.
How do i get the View of the actionbar's overflow button?

```
 private void showPopupDisplayLocalDescription() {
     View anchor = findViewById(R.id.menu_display_local_description);

     if (anchor == null) { //menuItem has overflowed.

          anchor = ?? <how do i get the view of the overflow icon?
     } 
     popup_localDescription = new PopupMenu(this, anchor);

     MenuInflater inflater = ... //the rest of the codes 

     popup_localDescription.show();
}
```